# Would NSTImer events block the main thread?

Tags: iphone, nstimer

When we use a NSTimer, once the call back is called after the mentioned interval, does the UI would be blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

> Timers work in conjunction with run
>   loops. To use a timer effectively, you
>   should be aware of how run loops
>   operate—see NSRunLoop and Threading
>   Programming Guide.
>
> Once scheduled on a run loop, the
>   timer fires at the specified interval
>   until it is invalidated. A
>   non-repeating timer invalidates itself
>   immediately after it fires. However,
>   for a repeating timer, you must
>   invalidate the timer object yourself
>   by calling its invalidate method.
>   Calling this method requests the
>   removal of the timer from the current
>   run loop; as a result, you should
>   always call the invalidate method from
>   the same thread on which the timer was
>   installed. Invalidating the timer
>   immediately disables it so that it no
>   longer affects the run loop. The run
>   loop then removes and releases the
>   timer, either just before the
>   invalidate method returns or at some
>   later point. Once invalidated, timer
>   objects cannot be reused.

I believe `NSTimer` does not block the UI thread. Also take a look at this previous SO question [NSTimer and updating UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131634/nstimer-and-updating-ui)

Answer (score 9):

That depends. Most of the time, this won't be a problem.

*If*, however, both of the following criteria are met, an `NSTimer` **will** block the UI thread:

1. The timer is scheduled on the `NSRunLoop` of the main thread. This will be the case whenever you created it by calling one of NStimer's `scheduledTimerWith...` class-methods on the main thread.
2. The method, which is called when the timer fires, performs "lengthy" tasks. Things like synchronously performed fetches/url-requests come to mind...

Comment: Why do the `scheduledTimerWith...` methods cause a problem? I'm getting UI blocking while my timer is running. I've created it using this method, I didn't realise that would be a problem. What are my other options? Thanks.

Comment: @user700774 those methods are not the problem. The problem is the amount of work that happens _synchronously_ within the timer-callback: The runloop, on which the timer is scheduled, will be blocked when the timer fires **for as long as the callback takes to return**. If your callback exits quickly, you will never notice this when the timer is scheduled on the main thread. If, however, you do any time-consuming processing there (just use a `sleep(5);` to simulate an extreme case)... If that's the case, just do that _asynchronously_ — `NSOperationQueue` and GCD are your friend, here.