# Repeating NSTimer locks UI thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, user-interface, nstimer

First of all, I know there are a few other StackOverflow questions about this subject, but I have read them all and I still am confused about what to do for my situation. I'm probably missing something obvious here, if you could help clarify that would be much appreciated!

I have a app which is doing a lot of work to animate images within a view - mainly comprised of a number of images moving in straight lines for a second or two at a time. I considered at first making them all simple, once off animations using UIView `animateWithDuration` for the whole duration of the movement. But I found that didn't give me a lot of power to intercept the movement or stop it or check where it was up to, so I scrapped that. My new approach is to use an NSTimer, firing 20 times per second, doing incremental movements. This way I also can intervene (almost) instantly to change the animation or stop it or update a status label based on how far through it is, etc, etc.

First of all...there probably is a better way than this. Feel free to suggest something better!

Assuming this is acceptable though, my issue now is that while these animations are happening, I can't click any of the other controls on the UI. I get no response. It's not like it's just slow or delayed either - the click never comes through. It seems that the NSTimer processing totally locks the UI - but only from new interactions. Changes I make to the UI within the timer processing method happen just fine, and are very snappy.

From what I've read this shouldn't happen. However I also saw a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945817/would-nstimer-events-block-the-main-thread#5957461) saying that if the timer processing is intensive then it *could* lock the UI thread. I don't see my processing to be that intensive here - certainly no resource requests, just a bit of data manipulating and animating some objects - but I could be underplaying it.

What are my options here? At first I thought I might create a new thread to kick off the timer. But I remember reading that the UI updates have to happen on the main thread anyway. Why is this? And plus, would that really solve the issue? Am I just asking too much of the device to process this timer as well as UI interactions? Is there something else I'm missing?

Any and all advice would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I've just found the cause of my UI blocking problem. I was using the `animateWithDuration` with blocks, but was not setting the options. Therefore `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` was not set. I changed it to set this option and my UI is happily responding now.

That said, I'll still leave this question open for specific suggestions regarding my overall approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider using CADisplayLink. From the documentation:

A CADisplayLink object is a timer object that allows your application to synchronize its drawing to the refresh rate of the display.

Your application creates a new display link, providing a target object and a selector to be called when the screen is updated. Next, your application adds the display link to a run loop.

Once the display link is associated with a run loop, the selector on the target is called when the screen’s contents need to be updated. The target can read the display link’s timestamp property to retrieve the time that the previous frame was displayed. For example, an application that displays movies might use the timestamp to calculate which video frame will be displayed next. An application that performs its own animations might use the timestamp to determine where and how displayed objects appear in the upcoming frame. The duration property provides the amount of time between frames. You can use this value in your application to calculate the frame rate of the display, the approximate time that the next frame will be displayed, and to adjust the drawing behavior so that the next frame is prepared in time to be displayed.

Your application can disable notifications by setting the paused property to YES. Also, if your application cannot provide frames in the time provided, you may want to choose a slower frame rate. An application with a slower but consistent frame rate appears smoother to the user than an application that skips frames. You can increase the time between frames (and decrease the apparent frame rate) by changing the frameInterval property.

When your application finishes with a display link, it should call invalidate to remove it from all run loops and to disassociate it from the target.

CADisplayLink should not be subclassed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure how everything is handled in your program, but you might want to just consider having one thread/timer that controls all of the objects and their movements. There's really no need to create a separate thread/timer for every single object, as that will easily cause problems.

You can just create a class for your moving items with some variables that contain information about their direction, speed, duration, etc, and then have a controlling thread/timer calculate and move the objects. You can then intervene onto the one main controller object instead of having to deal with many other objects.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've misled you. I do have just one timer that controls all of the objects and their movements - it's pretty much how you described. I thought even this may not be the best approach though. Regardless, any ideas on how this relates to the issue with the locked UI?

Comment: Sorry I was under the impression that you were using several timers or threads. That would have almost certain caused an issue with too many of them running. Glad you got your problem fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that even if you optimize this, timer based animation like this is not going to perform well.

You might want to ask about the specific things that you think you couldn't do with CoreAnimation.  If you solve those issues, you'll end up with a much better result than trying to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not quite sure how that would work though. For example, say I've got my image moving along a line and at a given point I want to work out where it is. Or without actually performing the animation, to find out where it should be. Or to cancel it. How do I do this using the simple UIView `animateWithDuration` approach?